# Reduce the line of code for this LINQ query

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I am using LINQ query in my code which need to be write multiple times with small changes in where condition. My query is

```
var sdata = from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
where r.Field<DateTime>("DAT_START").TimeOfDay.Hours < 20 &&
          r.Field<DateTime>("DAT_START").TimeOfDay.Hours >= 4
    group r by r["TXT_TARGET_CELL_ID"] into g
    select new
    {          

        CellID = g.Key,
        TotalCommCount = g.Count(),
        TotalDuration = g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("LNG_DURATION")),
        InSMSCount = g.Count(r => r.Field<Int16>("INT_DIRECTION") == 1 &&
                                  r.Field<Int16>("INT_CALL_DATA_TYPE") == 5),
        OutSMSCount = g.Count(r => r.Field<Int16>("INT_DIRECTION") == 2 &&
                                   r.Field<Int16>("INT_CALL_DATA_TYPE") == 5),
        InVoiceCount = g.Count(r => r.Field<Int16>("INT_DIRECTION") == 1 &&
                                    r.Field<Int16>("INT_CALL_DATA_TYPE") == 1),
        OutVoiceCount = g.Count(r => r.Field<Int16>("INT_DIRECTION") == 2 &&
                                     r.Field<Int16>("INT_CALL_DATA_TYPE") == 1),
        InVoiceDuration = g.Where(r => r.Field<Int16>("INT_DIRECTION") == 1 &&
                                    r.Field<Int16>("INT_CALL_DATA_TYPE") == 1)
                           .Sum(r => r.Field<int>("lNG_DURATION")),
        OutVoiceDuration = g.Where(r => r.Field<Int16>("INT_DIRECTION") == 2 &&
                                        r.Field<Int16>("INT_CALL_DATA_TYPE") == 1)
                           .Sum(r => r.Field<int>("LNG_DURATION")),
        Latitude = g.Any(s => s.Field<string>
                        ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS") != null && s.Field<string>
                        ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS").Trim() != "") ? g.First(s => s.Field<string>
                        ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS") != null && s.Field<string>
                        ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS").Trim() != "").Field<string>("TXT_LATITUDE") : "",
        Longitude = g.Any(s => s.Field<string>
                        ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS") != null && s.Field<string>
                        ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS").Trim() != "") ? g.First(s => s.Field<string>
                        ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS") != null && s.Field<string>
                        ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS").Trim() != "").Field<string>("TXT_LONGITUDE") : "",
        BTS_Address = g.Any(s => s.Field<string>
                        ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS") != null && s.Field<string>
                        ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS").Trim() != "") ? g.First(s => s.Field<string>
                        ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS") != null && s.Field<string>
                        ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS").Trim() != "").Field<string>("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS") : "",
        Azimuth = g.Any(s => s.Field<string>
                        ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS") != null && s.Field<string>
                        ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS").Trim() != "") ? g.First(s => s.Field<string>
                        ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS") != null && s.Field<string>
                        ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS").Trim() != "").Field<string>("TXT_AZIMUTH_DEG") : ""

    } into summary
orderby summary.TotalCommCount descending
select summary;
```

Here i need to change where condition only every time, remaining part remain same i.e Select new part. Can i write this query once in code and make a call to it with change in where condition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a new function like this:

```
public dynamic MyLinq(IEnumerable r, Predicate<Object> whereClause)
{
    return from r
    where whereClause(r)
        group r by r["TXT_TARGET_CELL_ID"] into g
        select new
        {          

            CellID = g.Key,
            TotalCommCount = g.Count(),
            TotalDuration = g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("LNG_DURATION")),
            InSMSCount = g.Count(r => r.Field<Int16>("INT_DIRECTION") == 1 &&
                                      r.Field<Int16>("INT_CALL_DATA_TYPE") == 5),
            OutSMSCount = g.Count(r => r.Field<Int16>("INT_DIRECTION") == 2 &&
                                       r.Field<Int16>("INT_CALL_DATA_TYPE") == 5),
            InVoiceCount = g.Count(r => r.Field<Int16>("INT_DIRECTION") == 1 &&
                                        r.Field<Int16>("INT_CALL_DATA_TYPE") == 1),
            OutVoiceCount = g.Count(r => r.Field<Int16>("INT_DIRECTION") == 2 &&
                                         r.Field<Int16>("INT_CALL_DATA_TYPE") == 1),
            InVoiceDuration = g.Where(r => r.Field<Int16>("INT_DIRECTION") == 1 &&
                                        r.Field<Int16>("INT_CALL_DATA_TYPE") == 1)
                               .Sum(r => r.Field<int>("lNG_DURATION")),
            OutVoiceDuration = g.Where(r => r.Field<Int16>("INT_DIRECTION") == 2 &&
                                            r.Field<Int16>("INT_CALL_DATA_TYPE") == 1)
                               .Sum(r => r.Field<int>("LNG_DURATION")),
            Latitude = g.Any(s => s.Field<string>
                            ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS") != null && s.Field<string>
                            ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS").Trim() != "") ? g.First(s => s.Field<string>
                            ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS") != null && s.Field<string>
                            ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS").Trim() != "").Field<string>("TXT_LATITUDE") : "",
            Longitude = g.Any(s => s.Field<string>
                            ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS") != null && s.Field<string>
                            ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS").Trim() != "") ? g.First(s => s.Field<string>
                            ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS") != null && s.Field<string>
                            ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS").Trim() != "").Field<string>("TXT_LONGITUDE") : "",
            BTS_Address = g.Any(s => s.Field<string>
                            ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS") != null && s.Field<string>
                            ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS").Trim() != "") ? g.First(s => s.Field<string>
                            ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS") != null && s.Field<string>
                            ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS").Trim() != "").Field<string>("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS") : "",
            Azimuth = g.Any(s => s.Field<string>
                            ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS") != null && s.Field<string>
                            ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS").Trim() != "") ? g.First(s => s.Field<string>
                            ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS") != null && s.Field<string>
                            ("TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS").Trim() != "").Field<string>("TXT_AZIMUTH_DEG") : ""

        } into summary
    orderby summary.TotalCommCount descending
    select summary;
}
```

Furthermore you should really be using constants for things like `"TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCATION_ADDRESS"` because it saves you from a simple mistake such as writing: `"TXT_TARGET_BTS_LOCAITON_ADDRESS"` and having it be compile time safe.

Edit: You would call this function with something like this:

```
var sdata = MyLinq(dt.AsEnumerable(), r => r.Field<DateTime>("DAT_START").TimeOfDay.Hours < 20 && r.Field<DateTime>("DAT_START").TimeOfDay.Hours >= 4)
```

you will probably need to change `Object` in `Predicate<Object>` to your actual type so that you can access the .Field values.

Comment: It all builds but gives me one error `Error cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable sdata`

Comment: return type of sdata is `System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<TElement> where TElement is anonymous type`

Answer (score 4):

You can break your predicate out into a separate method;

```cs
private static bool Where1(DT r)
{
    return r.Field<DateTime>("DAT_START").TimeOfDay.Hours < 20 &&
                        r.Field<DateTime>("DAT_START").TimeOfDay.Hours >= 4
}
```

This will be assignable to a Func that you can use right in your expression;

```
Func<DT, bool> myWhere
if(whereCase1)                             // Decide which Where predicate to use
   myWhere = Where1;
else
   myWhere = Where2;

var sdata = from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
            where myWhere(r)               // Use the chosen Where predicate.
            group r by r["TXT_TARGET_CELL_ID"]
            into g
            select new...
```

To build the `Where` condition in a slightly more dynamic way, you can make a function that returns the where condition instead of a bool;

```
    private static Func<DT, bool> WhereHoursAreBetween(int min, int max)
    {
        return r => r.Field<DateTime>("DAT_START").TimeOfDay.Hours < max &&
                    r.Field<DateTime>("DAT_START").TimeOfDay.Hours >= min;
    }
```

...which can then be used in the above example as;

```
myWhere = WhereHoursAreBetween(4, 20);
```

...which makes `myWhere` a condition that hours are between 4 and 20.

Comment: Do i need to make separate function for each Where condition ?

Comment: @RajeevKumar You could use lambdas or functions or build your Func from other Funcs, all are workable. Usually, it's a good way to define them as separate functions to make the code readable, a function called `WhereOrdersAreMax14DaysOld` is more descriptive than `x => x.Age.Days <= 14`. You can make them somewhat dynamic though, I'll add an example in a few minutes.

Comment: @RajeevKumar Added an example of a more dynamic way of building the `Where` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can refactor the expression by extracting the `where` part to a separate expression and then using it inside the bigger expression.

Comment: You should show an example of this - at the moment your answer is nothing more than a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function which receives a `Predicate`. Something like:

```
dynamic MyLinq(Predicate<Object> Check)
{
     return from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
     where Check(r)
     select r;
}
```